# weifenluo.winformsui.docking dll for Linux

Tags: c#, winforms, mono, ubuntu-10.04, docking

I have C# application which uses weifenluo.winformsui.docking.dll 2.3.1.0 for Docking. It runs nicely in Windows but does not run in Mono on Linux, ubuntu version 10.04 32-bit. It gives the exception with the weifenluo.winformsui.docking library.

Can anyone help me in solving this problem? or share the weifenluo.winformsui.docking.dll library which is compatible in both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This library unfortunately uses PInvoke to call Win32 APIs, so it is not portable for Linux usage.

Unless you decide to give up drag and drop support, then you can use a lite version,

http://www.lextm.com/2010/05/dockpanel-suite-tip-4-we-could-go-mono.html

This is the modified source code,

https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/tree/master/WinFormsUI

**Update： I have become one of the maintainers for this project. Please visit http://dockpanelsuite.com to check out the latest information.**

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am downloading the source code and test in Linux. I'll have to sacrifice drag and drop feature in Linux.